# Property 'grid-gap' doesn't exist in CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Working on an ASP.NET MVC project and visual studio isn't recognizing grid-gap.  Is it because of my version of CSS in this project?  I haven't been able to find where that is set, any recommendations?

Edit:
grid-row-gap also isn't recognized

Comment: You could try using `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap` instead? The shorthand might not working properly. Just a thought...

Comment: Perhaps this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/12/25/choosing-css-versions/

Comment: Perhaps update your version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

'grid-gap' has been deprecated in favor of 'gap'. In a similar vein 'grid-row-gap' and 'grid-column-gap' have been deprecated in favor of 'row-gap' and 'column-gap'.

Unfortunately, the new features aren't recognized by Visual Studio yet either.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-gap

Comment: As far as May 2020, 'grid-gap' is shown as "Obsolete" in VSC.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old.Just stumbled upon this problem myself and so logging the answer here.

This can be achieved with 'column-gap' and 'row-gap'. Visual studio code also recognizes it  as of October 2020.

Answer (score 0):

grid-column-gap not working in vs code instead of column gap working vs code. You are not to need "grid" just write column gap